# Visual studio 2013 community edition doesn't open solution file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, suo

I am using VS 2013 community edition. It doesn't  open one of my solution. I came to know that '.suo' file is a reason for that. After deleting .suo file its worked perfectly. But every time i need to delete that file whenever I opened that solution. Is that correct ? Am I missing anything ? Please help me.

Comment: Is there an error?  Have you run Visual Studio with debug logging turned on or done any other troubleshooting? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272(v=vs.120).aspx  The suo file is just preferences, but perhaps you have an addon installed that isn't behaving properly.

Comment: I don't  have any add on installed. And I don't receive any error from visual studio but received the notification which is saying 'Visual studio is too busy'.  I checked with the activity log but its doesn't get updated.